# github: comment will be remaining even if reload browser, why?

Tags: github, frontend

When I write a comment with github's issue page, I noticed that the comment body remains even if I reload the browser.

[image]

I have checked localStorage, sessionStorage, cacheStorage, IndexedDB, cookie,
but I found no instance of the sentence that I wrote.

Also, I have checked the network tab of Chrome Devtool, but I could not find any suspicious network traffic.

How does github.com achieve this recovery function?

Answer (score 2):

They are using `SessionStorage` to do this:

**On Page Leave:**

1. select all of the input fields with `.js-session-resumable` as selector
2. put {id, value} pair of inputs in an array
3. put it in `SessionStorage` as `session-resume:/current/page/path`

**On Page Load:**

1. check if there are any values with `session-resume:/current/page/path` key in `SessionStorage`
2. if yes, update values of inputs and remove this record from `SessionStorage`

*Note:* If you write a comment in a page (without submitting it) and go to another page, then you can see your comment saved in `SessionStorage`.

Comment: In original post: "I have checked localStorage, sessionStorage, cacheStorage, IndexedDB, cookie, but I found no instance of the sentence that I wrote."

Comment: @jhpratt as I mentioned in the answer, they are removing the record in page load. So, you will not see your sentence in SessionStorage when the page is loaded!